# Simple log filtering with Flask

Tags: python, flask, logging, python-logging

I'm new to Flask and I'm having trouble filtering out some logs. My use case is simple: I don't want to log health check queries, which hit the route `/health`.

Here's what I have:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.logging import logging

class NoHealth(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return 'GET /health' not in record.getMessage()

no_health = NoHealth()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.addFilter(no_health)
app.logger.setLevel('INFO')

@app.route('/health')
def health_check():
    return "OK"
```

The logs I want to drop look like this:

`127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2020 17:51:03] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

They're still coming through, however. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access logs are written by `werzeug` (web server running flask app in this case).
So, better option would be to increase logging level to `warning`:

```
logging.getLogger("werkzeug").setLevel('WARNING')
```

In case you really want to use custom filter `NoHealth`, you can go with following solution:

```
logging.getLogger("werkzeug").addFilter(NoHealth())
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Ultimately I want to send the health check logs to DEBUG and keep seeing regular access logs as normal, but now that I know where they're coming from that's easy.